# Multiple arguments into bash script

Tags: bash, gpio

I'm new to bash and I've started working on a simple bash script to turn on or off GPIO pins on raspberryPi. I'd like to provide arguments to the script like this: script.sh GPIO_number start/on/off/clean. How do I continue this script the most efficient way? I'm stuck at the second argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]; then
        echo "Usage: gpioaction.sh GPIO start/on/off/clean"
        exit 1
fi

if [ -z $2 ]; then
        echo "Usage: gpioaction.sh GPIO start/on/off/clean"
        exit 1
fi

PIN=$1

start=$(echo "$PIN" > /sys/class/gpio/export;echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN/direction;echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN/value)
on=$(echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN/value)
off=&(echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN/value)
clean=&(echo "$PIN" > /sys/class/gpio/unexport)
```

Comment: Define "I'm stuck at the second argument." You appear to know how to use positional parameters `$1` and `$2`. Then what's the problem?

Comment: @4ae1e1 Well, $2 can be defined for start, on, off or clean. Can you write me an example for: script.sh 19 start and script.sh 19 clean

Comment: Still not sure what you mean, but looks like you need `case`: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs.

Comment: You need to quote `$1` and `$2` (e.g., `if [ -z "$1" ]; then`.

Comment: @4ae1r1 Let me try to explain more. I can only use two arguments at the same time, both are mandatory. First argument is the pin number ($1), and the second argument has multiple options ($2). With the second argument, you could start, on, off or clean the selected GPIO PIN. I guess I need the case statements like your mentioned already, but it would be very helpfull, If you could write me an example for my case

Comment: search for `[bash] case` here on S.O. There should be many helpful examples. Good luck.

Comment: Also, http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend -- ideal to run code through there before bringing it here, just so we don't go kibitzing about things like missing quotes (which, in the case of `[ -z $1 ]`, cause very real bugs).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be 'close' - what you have assigns values to variables (a = output from some command) and will quickly run through all commands; perhaps something like this is closer to what you are looking for:

```
function gpio_start {
echo "$PIN" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out"  > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN/direction
echo "1"    > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN/value
}
###
case "$2" ### here you could use functions or simple commands lines
in
        start) replace_with_fucntion_or_start_steps ;;
           on) replace_with_fucntion_or_on_steps ;;
          off) replace_with_fucntion_or_off_steps ;;
        clean) replace_with_fucntion_or_clean_steps ;;
            *) echo "Usage: gpioaction.sh GPIO start/on/off/clean" ; exit ;;
esac
###  
Another, closer to what you have example:  

case "$2"
in
        start) gpio_start ;; ## use function for multiple commands
           on) echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN/value ;;
          off) echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN/value ;;
        clean) echo "$PIN" > /sys/class/gpio/unexport ;;
            *) echo "Usage: gpioaction.sh GPIO start/on/off/clean" ; exit ;;
esac
```

If you use the case statement then you don't really need your 'second check' using the 'if' statement.

:)
Dale

Comment: The `function` keyword makes your code incompatible with POSIX sh without adding any benefit over compliant syntax. Better to define functions as `gpio_start() { ... }` than `function gpio_start { ... }`.

Comment: Does your comment help the original poster?  I think that the person asking the question would be better served with a 'better answer' and not by secondary commentary which may or may not be relevant to the environment where the code will be used.  While your comment may have merit, I do not see it as being helpful for a NOOB question (i.e. 
"I'm new to bash..." != I would like to have a deep discourse on all the quirks with shell scripting...

Comment: If this advice helps prevent the OP from learning a set of habits which would lead to surprising behavior (other shells giving parse errors with their scripts down the line), then certainly, that's helpful. That said, the intended audience of this comment was *you*, in the hopes that you'd edit your answer to demonstrate better practices to those, such as the original poster, who are (indeed) early enough in the learning process to not be as well-suited to make those distinctions themselves.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need such 'help' - again, keeping a focus on the question - the other comments were less than helpful to the original question - which was not about POSIX; so far, the only response that I can see with a 'helpful intent' is mine; again, if you have a 'better answer' then please do post! Also, I  do appreciate you being non-anonymous - it's refreshing!  :)

Comment: I can't provide anything I'm confident would be a better answer without a better question -- the OP's intent is too poorly specified to know what they really want (which is also why I can't tell if this answer is or isn't helpful, thus lack of any voting, either up or down). On principle I disagree with your decision to reject suggested refinements (which would seem to be categorical, given lack of any specific argument re: merit or lack thereof), but that is of course your choice.